# Use returned data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I get some data from a table

Data is returned into an array like this

```
Array ( [id_widget] => 11 [id_user] => 7 [active] => 1 )
```

Then I am trying to use this "id_widget" and "entryemail" to insert them into another table.

"newentry" comes from an input, but I don't know how to post the "id_widget"

This is my model function

```
public function addentry($data) {
    $this->db->insert('entries', array(
        'id_widget' => $data['id_widget'],
        'entryemail' => $data['entryemail']
    ));
}
```

This is my controller function:

```
public function entercontest() {

    $entry = array(
        'id_widget' => $this->widget[0]['id_widget'],
        'entryemail' => $_POST['entryemail']
    );

    $this->model->addentry($entry);
}
```

It works to insert "entryemail" if I comment `id_widget` line everywhere.

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->widget)` in the `entercontest` method yeild?

Comment: are you sure there is filed name 'id_widget' in your table 'entries' ?

Comment: @webbiedave Notice: Undefined property: Widget::$widget in C:\xampp\htdocs\w\controllers\widget.php on line 34
NULL

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Yes I am pretty sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't occur when getting the value from the array `$data['id_widget']`. The error occurs in the `entercontent` function because you're populating the array with an undefined value because `$this->widget` is undefined.

Make sure `$this->widget` is defined and has the data before using it.